# Different factors of $4\pi$ and $\epsilon_0$ in Poisson equation

Tags: electromagnetism, units, conventions, si-units

Some authors claim the Poisson equation is $$\nabla^2 \psi = -\dfrac{\rho}{\epsilon\epsilon_0}$$ (e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%E2%80%93Boltzmann_equation)) whereas other ones (e.g. [Andelmann](http://hwiki.liebel-lab.org/wiki/images/9/90/AndelmannReview.pdf)) claim it is $$\nabla^2 \psi = -4\pi\dfrac{\rho}{\epsilon}.$$ I guess $\epsilon_0$ is taken to be one but how would you explain the absence or presence of the $4\pi$ multiplier? Is it related to some choice of units?

Comment: It is the choice of units, in particular [Gaussian Units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_units).

Comment: Ok thank you @KyleKanos, and this occurs for the unit of $\epsilon$, doesn't it ?

Comment: More or less. There's a bit more rigorous a proof (involves writing the 4 Maxwell equations in the form $\nabla\cdot\mathbf E=k_1\rho$ etc, together with the Coulomb force to get that replacing $1/\epsilon_0\to4\pi$.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1673/2451 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28673/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74254/2451 and links therein.