# Is equation $1/4πε_0$ in Coulombs law a scalar? Plus a question involving Jefimenko's equations

Tags: electromagnetism, units, coulombs-law

Is the equation of $1/4πε_0$ in Coulombs law a scalar? Also, does this equation equate to Coulombs constant?

In addition, why does Jefimenko use $H=1/4π...$ in his equations? What is the significance of $1/4π$?

I'm looking at Jefimenko's equations and I can't tell if he's stating scalars are the 'cause' of vectors. Can someone help clear this up for me? I know that current and charge are scalars but I'm not sure if $∂B/∂t$ is suppose to translate to a weber somehow. He's using the terminology '*electric charge*' and 'current' causing $E$ and $B$ fields yet he then has a part that says E is a consequence of $∂B/∂t$. So how does ∂B/∂t relate to charges and currents?

Is it true that $∂B/∂t$ is equal a scalar?

Comment: The *factor* 1/$4\pi\epsilon_0$ is a scalar, and yes, it is the [Coulomb's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb_constant).

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1673/2451 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28673/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Provide the reference you are using for Jefimenko's equations, please.

Answer (score 2):

*This is the answer to the first part of the question (which, I think, should be split into two different questions.)*

Factor $1/(4\pi\epsilon_0)$ is specific to the SI system of units. Many scientific works use other system of units, among which is [cgs system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centimetre%E2%80%93gram%E2%80%93second_system_of_units), particularly popular in electrodynamics and condensed matter. In addition, there are systems of units specific to other fields, such as astronomy, particle physics, nuclear physics, etc.

The choice of a system of units is a matter of convenience, often dictated by some of the following reasons

- having the scale of units compatible with the natural scales (i.e., to avoid writing too many factors $\times 10^{\pm x}$)
- not having to write over and over physical constants (by setting $c=1, \hbar=1$, etc.)
- having equations in a more convenient form.

The latter case is relevant here: in SI units the differential form of the Gauss' law and the resulting form of the Coulomb law are
$$
\nabla\cdot\mathbf{E}=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}\longrightarrow F = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q_1q_2}{r^2},
$$
whereas in cgs units they take form:
$$
\nabla\cdot\mathbf{E}=4\pi\rho\longrightarrow F = \frac{q_1q_2}{r^2},
$$
Factor $4\pi$ originates here from applying the Gauss law to a sphere with surface area $4\pi r^2$. Excluding this factor from the Maxwell equation, results in its reappearance in the expression for the Coulomb law and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

**"Is the equation of 1/4πε0 in Coulombs law a scalar?"** an equation cannot be scalar.

**"Also, does this equation equate to Coulombs constant?"** a constant can equate an equation.

**"In addition, why does Jefimenko use H=1/4π...
in his equations? What is the significance of 1/4π?"**

To understand 1/4π you should look at the whole equation i.e.

$E = \frac{q}{\epsilon  \;4 \pi r^2 }$

You should be able to recall that $4 \pi r^2$ is area of a sphere. This is because the electric field which is created by the charge $q$ is spherically symmetric.

**"I can't tell if he's stating scalars are the 'cause' of vectors."** Some quantities are scalar such as mass, temperature, and all the constants in physics. However, the scalar and vector quantities can be related using differentiation. Gradient of a scalar field (not a scalar, but a scalar field) is a vector and divergence of a vector field (again not a vector, but a vector field) is a scalar.

**"He's using the terminology 'electric charge' and 'current' causing E and B fields"** there are different ways to create E and B field. electric charges can create E field but this is not the only way to create E field. B field can be created by current.

E field can also be created by ∂B/∂t i.e. changing the B field.

**"So how does ∂B/∂t relate to charges and currents?"** you can use current (which is moving charges) to create B. then if you change the current (the speed at which the charges are moving), you create ∂B/∂t and it gives you E.

**"Is it true that ∂B/∂t is equal a scalar?"** ∂B/∂t is a vector because B is a vector. when a vector is multiplied or divided by a scalar the result is still a vector.