# Power of electron density in Bloch's exchange term

Tags: condensed-matter, dimensional-analysis, density-functional-theory

Exchange term introduced by Felix Bloch is given by

$$
E_x = c_2 \int n(\vec{r})^{4 / 3} d\vec{r}
$$

In the example 1.6.7 of the attached [reference](https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/u7losf1CQzi5aLH9QuM40w_9b05beadfa3f42b3993aea8de2d7d1fd_LN_TF.pdf?Expires=1611446400&Signature=FMkzhIy2qA1uZLWUmd9dzkXIN3JLIzW1dc02DIdgi6nGHrE%7El1lBaWSzaHF2EJrCafm9tMNS6D5YLDEnWt-BXDLiNygjPnVKl1D%7E6m31PhFOFhpsusLmA%7Es4urH7oAA5bYsD5q7GF4UDa7nKu8u7Ex6bLuQjZ2iWPmPt4qFGbYc_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A), the power of $n(\vec{r})$ is derived as following

$$
E_x \propto \int d\vec{r} e^2 n(\vec{r})^d
$$

And the argument is that, that the dimensions of integrand is of energy density, so

$$
\text{energy density} = \left[ \frac{M}{LT^2} \right] \implies e^2 n^d = \left[ \frac{ML^3}{T^2} L^{-3d} \right]
$$

I did not understand why there is a $L^3$ term in the second fraction above, because the dimensions of energy is

$$
\left[ E \right]  = \left[ ML^2T^{-2} \right]
$$

Comment: Is $e$ the elementary charge?

Comment: @Jakob Yes, it is elementary charge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left hand side of the equation has the dimension energy, while on the right hand side there is a $L^3$ (from the integral) times $e^2\,n^d$. The dimension of $n^d$ is $L^{-3d}$ and the dimension of $e^2$ is given by $M\,L^3\, T^{-2}$. Hence we obtain the dimension of $e^2\,n^d$ as

$$ M\, L^3\, T^{-2}\, L^{-3d} \quad.$$

Finally, we see that the right hand side has thus a dimension of
$$M\, L^6\,T^{-2}\,L^{-3d}$$ and in order for both sides to have the same dimension, we require $d=4/3$.

**Edit**: The dimensions of $e^2$ as given here can be found in cgs units, see for example [Physical dimensions for the Coulomb force in SI and CGS](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1673/physical-dimensions-for-the-coulomb-force-in-si-and-cgs). Also in this reference, on page 12, the same argument is used: https://www.aimspress.com/fileOther/PDF/Materials/matersci-04-01372.pdf.

Comment: Thank you! Interplay between SI units and CGS units hid the essential part.

Comment: well, yeah. I think that using $\frac{e^2}{\epsilon_0}$ in the SI case should lead to the same conclusion.